# jpa criteria error or misplaced

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi I got a table as follow
(User table)

```
+----------+------------+
| Code     | reference  |
+----------+------------+
| adfasd   | hello      |
+----------+------------+
| wertwtw  | it works   |
+----------+------------+
```

when I make a method ==> findByCodeContaining(String param) -it works [as this link says](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.named-parameters)

when I make a method ==> findByreferenceContaining(String param) -it works

But, when I make a method ==> findByCodeContainingOrfindByreferenceContaining(String param)
it does not work. even though [I follow this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

I would like to know why it does not work and where did I make it wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is wrong. Remove the second 'findBy` part

```
findByCodeContainingOrReferenceContaining(String param)
```

I would also expect it to be `Reference` and not `reference`. Depending on how you created your entities.

Comment: thanks
But, I do not know what is wrong with my code, I still got error.
I think problem is my other code or something.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as follow:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.Code like ?1 or u.reference like ?2 ")
findByCodeContainingOrReferenceContaining(String param, String Param);
```

by following [the above link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.named-parameters)..
thanks again.

Comment: It's permissible to "accept" your own answer. You don't get the points for it, but people searching the site months or even years from now who find your question will know, quicker, that this was how you fixed it.